# How to configure gpg-agent to work correctly with obnam?

Tags: backup, gpg, gpg-agent

I'm trying to set up the de-duplicating backup program obnam so that it  backups encrypted chunks on a remote server (raspberry pi B3 through ssh with USB hard drive) but can't get it even starting to work; already at first invocation (when it wants to add the `<local_user>` as a client) it exits with:

```
$ obnam backup ~/.obnam.conf
adding clientERROR: gpg: can't query passphrase in
batch mode gpg: decryption failed: secret key not available
```

(After which obnam's lock file needs to be manually removed, but that's another story.) 
The client is a Fedora 18 VM in Qubes-OS with (hopefully) gpg-agent configured correctly as per the man page with 
~/.bashrc containing:

```
GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_TTY
#
if [ -f "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info" ]; then
  . "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info"
  export GPG_AGENT_INFO
  export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
  export SSH_AGENT_PID
fi
```

and with 
 ~/.bash_profile containing:

```
eval $(gpg-agent --daemon --enable-ssh-support --write-env-file "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info")
```

All according to gpg-agent's man file. I can see that 'it works' when the VM is restarted as the .gpg-agent-info file actually exists, the variables (GPG_TTY, GPG_AGENT_INFO, SSH_AUTH_SOCK, SSH_AGENT_PID) are set, and
they are exported and can be echoed to the terminal.

The obnam configuration file contains:

```
repository = sftp://<remote_user>@<rmeote_IP_address>/home/<remote_user>/backups/obnam-repository/
encrypt-with = APENHEUL
```

after making sure both secret and public keys with Key-ID APENHEUL actually exist. 
The versions of the programs used are:

gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.0.22 
libgcrypt 1.5.3 
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.16 
obnam --version: 1.5 
OpenSSH_6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment 'use-agent' in .gnupg/gpg.conf. Embarrassing but true...